# Regular expression matching URL parameters

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following two strings

```
?room=any_characters123&name=John

?room=any_characters123
```

I want to extract "any_characters123" using regular expression.

I've tried

```
(?<=room=)(\w)+(?=\&)
```

but this one fails on the second string (because the matched string must end with "&").

How can I edit my regular expression so that it matches any_characters123 in both strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since javascript won't support lookbehinds, you need to use capturing group.

```
\?room=(\w+)
```

**Example:**

```
> var s = "?room=any_characters123&name=John"
> var s1 = "?room=any_characters123"
undefined
> var re = /\?room=(\w+)/;
undefined
> console.log(re.exec(s)[1])
any_characters123
undefined
> console.log(re.exec(s1)[1])
any_characters123
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using JS, lookbehind is not supported. You can modify the regex as follows:

```
room=([^&]+)
```

Comment: Amazingly this oldest correct answer remained without upvote +1

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `*` in the end of your expression:

```
room=(\w+)\&*?
```

It will test for zero or plus ocurrences of `&`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
/room=(\w+)&?/
/*
    find "room=" then match any word characters (at least one) until you
    possibly hit "&"
*/
```

Example:

```
/room=(\w+)&?/.test("?room=any_characters123")
// => true
"?room=any_characters123".match(/room=(\w+)&?/)
// => ["room=any_characters123", "any_characters123"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the string through two regex tests, the one you already have, and then this one:

```
(?<=room=)(\w){1,}$
```